# Magento 2.4.3 not showing mega menu

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation, megamenu

Magento 2.4.3 is not showing the Mega Menu navigation. If I inspect the page, I get a "esi:include" tag instead of the menu. I have been following the extension guide here https://landofcoder.gitbook.io/magento-2-megamenu/config-and-usage/show-menu-on-frontend
but still nothing. I have also tried to disable the varnish cache from Magento backend, nothing, any idea to get the menu showing?

Answer (score -1):

If i am not wrong your are using a already build module for menu . For that install it in right directory and run the cmd in your terminal i am assuming you are using linux os so add sudo before every cmd

1. sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. sudo php bin/magetno setup:static-content:deploy -f
3. sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
4. sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
5. sudo php bin/magento cache:clean

**before runing this check is your module is there in module list**
6. sudo php bin/magento module:status
7. sudo php bin/magento module:enable Module_Name
then again check the the module list
https://meetanshi.com/blog/display-magento-2-module-list/
check this link for checking the output